# global definition missing in kernel ext4 function

Tags: linux-kernel

trace_ext4_discard_blocks-- I wonder how and where do they implemented this fn., inside linux kernel code. Normal ctags, cscope didn't helps. I strongly suspect it is implemented somewhere in asm but I donno' how to catch this in code. Any pointers or tricks?

Comment: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.0/source/include/trace/events/ext4.h#L586 and the TRACE_POINT macro likely defines `trace_ext4_discard_blocks`

Comment: thanks for the info..

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15.4/source/Documentation/trace/tracepoints.txt) is the starting point for the tracepoint documentation.

[Here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15.4/source/include/trace/events/ext4.h#L588) is the definition of the function.

[Here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15.4/source/include/linux/tracepoint.h#L173) is where the `TRACE_POINT` macro ends up.